# Create thumbnail from video using ffmpeg

Tags: video, amazon-web-services, ffmpeg

I need to create a thumbnail from video while uploading it to CDN.

I have been searching for this found [this](http://blog.amnuts.com/2007/06/22/create-a-random-thumbnail-of-a-video-file/) but I am not able to get the screen shot even after following steps.

I am using jwplayer for [playing video](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26887917/show-jwplayer-preview-image-from-video-without-image)

Can someone help me to create thumbnail while uploading video using ffmpeg

Answer (score 94, accepted):

I do not know a way to make a screenshot WHILE uploading, but I do know how to do it after.

The simplest code is:

```
ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -ss 00:00:01.000 -vframes 1 output.png
```

Run this script after you have uploaded the file. It should take only a short amount of time if the screenshot is taken in the beginning of the video. (first minute e.g.).

I do not think it is possible to take a screenshot while the file is still being uploaded.

Edit: 
removed `-f image2` as it is guessed correct by ffmpeg

Comment: The format is normally guessed from the output file extension, so `-f image2` is not needed here.

Comment: what is `-f image2` ?? here

Comment: -f is the format of the input/output (normally guessed by ffmpeg) and image2 is the demuxer. See ffmpeg documenation for more info: https://www.ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-formats.html#Demuxers

@LordNeckbeard removed it from the answer

Comment: @hitesh `-f image2` is generally used if the output is a variable.

Comment: where to give output image file path

Comment: absolute path: foo/bar/output.png

Comment: If you put -ss before -i, then you won't have to wait for the first minute of frames to go through. However, most decoders can't go to an exact timestamp, so you may end up slightly before your timestamp (eg 00:00:58 instead of 00:01:00).

Comment: What's the `$` sign?

Comment: @llogan Do you happen to know what the `$` sign means? I googled linux dollar sign, and I found  an example: `lsattr "$(realpath /etc/resolv.conf)"` but I still don't understand why drumkruk is not using parentheses here.

Comment: @Shayan It is just a generic placeholder. To be more clear he could have simply used `input.mp4`. In some languages the `$` indicates a variable.

Comment: @llogan you are right, it was not needed to have the variable there.

Comment: But if shorter than 1sec, what will be?

Answer (score 20):

The other answers are fine... but for most "video" content, **JPEG** is a more space-efficient choice for a thumbnail image. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10234065/1026023) discusses JPEG quality settings.

And often you'll want to specify the **thumbnail size** - the below command ([source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42024302/1026023)) will scale the video down to fit in a 320x320 box (maintaining the aspect ratio by decreasing the smaller edge -- i.e. 320px on the long edge):

```
ffmpeg -ss 00:00:01.00 -i input.mp4 -vf 'scale=320:320:force_original_aspect_ratio=decrease' -vframes 1 output.jpg
```

Comment: Awesome. This is important. No one had mentioned about setting the image quality. Thanks.

Comment: Hi "-vframes 1" results a blank black image

Answer (score 9):

According to this documentation https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Seeking and my personal tests you should change places of -ss and -i like this

```
ffmpeg -ss 00:00:01.000 -i input.mp4 -vframes 1 output.png
```

The operation will become much faster as no video decoding will be done. Video will be parsed using keyframes instead, which is very fast.

Answer (score 0):

```
$ffmpegPath = exec('which ffmpeg');
$ffprobePath = exec('which ffprobe');

$command = "$ffprobePath -v error -show_entries format=duration -of default=noprint_wrappers=1:nokey=1 $input_video";
$video_duration = shell_exec($command);

$thumbnails_output = 'output%02d.png';
$command = "$ffmpegPath -i $input_video -vf fps=3/$video_duration $thumbnails_output";
shell_exec($command)
```

Comment: Code only answers are **not considered good answers**, and are likely to be downvoted and/or deleted because they are **less useful** to a community of learners. Answers with an explanation are always more helpful. The solution may be obvious to you. To others it may not. Please explain what it does, and how it's different from existing answers. Otherwise this answer may be flagged as [Low Quality](https://stackoverflow.com/help/review-low-quality). Here are some guidelines for [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

This is my bash script to create n thumbnails of a video (in the example there are 11 but you can change it)
It does it at regular intervals over the entire length of the video.

```
#!/bin/bash

for input_video in "$@"
do
  duracion=$(ffprobe -v error -show_entries format=duration -of default=noprint_wrappers=1:nokey=1 "$input_video");
  #echo $duracion;

  ffmpeg -i "$input_video" -vf fps=11/$duracion "$input_video%02d.png";
  #echo "  ffmpeg -i \"$input_video\" -vf fps=3/$duracion  \"$input_video%02d.png\"";

done
```