# Make Multiple thumbnails from video with ffmpeg

Tags: ffmpeg

I have a question,How can I create multiple thumbnail at different times of video?
Mean operate like this schematic:

```
  input.mp4 =>  00:10:00 => 1.jpg
  input.mp4 =>  00:20:00 => 2.jpg
  input.mp4 =>  00:25:00 => 3.jpg
```

I mean, with one command I produce multiple thumbnails from different frames.
Is there any recommendation?
Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use

```
ffmpeg -ss 10:00 -i in.mp4 \
       -ss 20:00 -i in.mp4 \
       -ss 25:00 -i in.mp4 \
         -map 0:v:0 -vframes 1 1.jpg \
         -map 1:v:0 -vframes 1 2.jpg \
         -map 2:v:0 -vframes 1 3.jpg
```

Comment: It returns this : `Automatic encoder selection failed for output stream #0:1. Default encoder for format image2 (codec none) is probably disabled. Please choose an encoder manually.
Error selecting an encoder for stream 0:1`

Comment: Thank you so much.

Comment: When I'm using this command on some files, the ffmpeg output is : `Output file is empty, nothing was encoded (check -ss / -t / -frames parameters if used)`

Answer (score 0):

Although it does not create thumbnails at specific positions, I think you may find it useful for your use case [my answer to this other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27145238/create-thumbnail-from-video-using-ffmpeg/73694172#73694172) where multiple thumbnails are made at regular intervals