# Generate Multiple Thumbnails from Multiple Videos (with FFmpeg)

Tags: ffmpeg

I have multiple videos in different locations, something like:
D:\Folder 1\001.ts
E:\Folder 2\abc.avi
F:\Foder X\视频.mp4 (some videos name are in non-English languages)

And I  already have a filelist.txt with these file path in it

> file 'D:\Folder 1\001.ts'

> file 'E:\Folder 2\abc.avi'

> file 'F:\Foder X\视频.mp4'

For each video, I want to generate 3 images, starting from 00:00:10, then next image every 10 sec.
The name of the image should be the name of the video + number staring from 1, something like
001_1.jpg, 001_2.jpg, 001_3.jpg
abc_1.jpg, abc_2.jpg, abc_3.jpg
视频_1.jpg, 视频_2.jpg, 视频_3.jpg

how to do it in Windows 10?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27145238/create-thumbnail-from-video-using-ffmpeg

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27145238/create-thumbnail-from-video-using-ffmpeg, this only allplies to one video, and the output image name is not the same as video name.

Comment: You will need to have to write a bash script  like in https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/422439/bash-script-with-ffmpeg, where you define your inputs/outputs and your 3 images logic

Comment: Windows might be different but the idea is the same.

Comment: thanks, but I don't know how to do loop in the Windows

Comment: Search for "Powershell ffmpeg scripting"

Answer (score 0):

1. make a folder with the videos
2. save this code as a batch file [.bat] inside same folder

   > @echo off
   >
   > setlocal ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
   >
   > set /a u=30 for %%m in (*.*) do for /l %%x in (10, 10, 30) do (
   >
   > echo.
   >
   > echo output= %%m_%%x
   >
   > ffmpeg -v error -stats -ss %%x -i "%%m" -frames:v 1 "%%m"_%%x.jpg)
3. double click the batch file